# Period representation in SQL Server including not finished ones

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Since the beginning of my database build, I've been asking myself a question about period.

Let's say that i have a table called tbPeriod :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbPeriod]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [startDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [endDate] [datetime] NULL,
)
```

I want to represent periods as :

- 2014/02/03 => 2014/03/13
- 2013/01/05 => Today
- 2013/01/05 => 2014/03/14 (<> Today)

For the first one, no problem.
For the second, i've huge difficulties to choose what data I should use to represent "Today".
My first thought was to choose NULL values. But i've faced a lot of comparaison problems due to the fact that NULL>2014/01/01 for example is always false. 
Of course, i could extend the comparaison definition but it was becoming too big and not  natural.

Use of a "compare" function could have done the trick but functions have the drownback to avoid index use.

I've finally chose "9999/12/31" date as it makes correct all comparaison i've had to do. But it's really ugly.

Have you ever face a similar issue and how did you solve it?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NULL` like this for example:

```
DECLARE @PeriodStartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @PeriodEndDate DATETIME

SET @PeriodStartDate = CONVERT(DateTime, '20140101')
SET @PeriodEndDate = NULL

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE SaveDate BETWEEN @PeriodStartDate AND ISNULL(@PeriodEndDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

This selects everything between Jan 1st 14 and either today (`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) if `@PeriodEndDate` is `null` or `@PeriodEndDate`.

Personally I'd always represent an open period of time using a `NULL` timestamp for the end of the period.

Please note that is it not possible to compare `NULL` to anything, because `NULL` is neither equal nor unequal anything else. To check whether something is `NULL`, use `IF (XYZ IS NULL) ...` or `... IS NOT NULL ...`.

Comment: I didn't know about between and it solves lot of my problems. I knew for null behaviour. Anyway, you made clear in my mind the "open period" concept (it's not "today" bu rather an opened period that will close one day) Thanks for the help.